# Is there any way to resize the images based on screen resolution with out using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am planning to use a big banner image in my website(976X450).Now in higher resolution monitors the image should stretch to occupy the space. Is there any way to do this with out using different images for different resolution?

Comment: the image is going to stretch which will affect all the proportions. Did you want to tile the image (i.e. repeat it along the x-axis) or to fill the space with something else like a background colour? You could set `width:100%` as the CSS style on the image

Comment: I can't imagine how slow a 976x450 image will load. O.M.G.

Comment: I don't want to tile the image and I want to fill the space with the same image

Answer (score 1):

Just start with the detection of screen dimensions and continue from there:

```
var width = screen.width;
var height = screen.height;

var img = document.getElementById(image_id);

img.height = img.height * width / img.width;
img.width = width;
```

**Update**:

Use CSS:

```
img#in_question { width: 100% }
```

Comment: I thought it was supposed to be without javascript? -- Just making sure!

Comment: +1 for the updated answer. Not indicating height will keep original proportions, which is intended by OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
#HeaderImage {
   height: 20%;
   width: 100%;
   background-repeat:repeat-x;

}
```